# How I can fix the problem with send-message method?

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I have one trouble with code compiling. I must write the web application which will behave the chat. Now, I wrote the chat.service but, I have the problem. Why? Please help me. I send the photos of chat.service.enter image description here. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aUnHW.jpg)

> { Argument of type '{ message: string; timeSent: string; userName: Observable; email: any; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ChatMessage[]'.}

Send my code too:

```
@Injectable()
export class ChatService {
  user: any;
  chatMessages: AngularFireList<ChatMessage[]>;
  chatMessage: ChatMessage;
  userName: Observable<string>;

  constructor(
    // create value for angularFirebase
    private db: AngularFireDatabase,
    private afAuth: AngularFireAuth
  ) {
      this.afAuth.authState.subscribe(auth => { // check the auth user message
        if (auth !== undefined && auth !== null) {
          this.user = auth;
        }
      });
    }
// send message method with get time and get back message
  sendMessage(message: string) {
    const timestamp = this.getTimeStamp();
    const email = this.user.email;
    this.chatMessages = this.getMessages();
    this.chatMessages.push({
      message: message,
      timeSent: timestamp,
      userName: this.userName,
      email: email,
    });
  }

  getMessages(): AngularFireList<ChatMessage[]> {
    return this.db.list('message', ref => ref.orderByKey().limitToLast(25));
  }

  private getTimeStamp() {
    const now = new Date();
    const date = now.getUTCFullYear() + '/' + (now.getUTCMonth() + 1) + '/' + now.getUTCDate();
    const time = now.getUTCHours() + ':' + now.getUTCMinutes() + ':' + now.getUTCSeconds();

    return (date + ' ' + time);

   }
}
```

Comment: What does the ChatMessage interface look like?

Comment: I attached the photo of my code

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Pictures of code are not helpful. They can't be copied to try out or understand. They may not render well for some devices and cannot be restyled to deal with user accessibilty.
Please include the code in your question and use formatting for it.

Comment: I've posted my code too. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're passing an object to a function that expects an array.
Judging from the small snippet provided, you could just wrap your data into an  array containing only that element.
Might be able to get the code working.
Please take a look at @kurt-hamilton suggestion and improve your question

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes from this code fragment:

```
this.chatMessages = this.getMessages();
this.chatMessages.push({
  message: message,
  timeSent: timestamp,
  userName: this.userName,
  email: email,
});
```

In the first line you initialize `chatMessages` to be an `AngularFireList<ChatMessage[]>`, which is a type defined by AngularFire2. Then in the next line you try to `push` a new item to that type, which is not a valid operation as the object does not seem to be a valid `ChatMessage`. You'll want to make sure that the JSON you pass is correct for `ChatMessage`, or actually create a `ChatMessage` object and push that to the `chatMessages`.